# Append MYSQL dump to a table

Tags: mysql

I am getting two different dumps from two databases ,
All i need to do is , i need to append dump in to a single table , is this possible in mysql ..?

ex:- consider two sql files , first.sql file , second.sql file .

First.sql File has

```
name  date
name1 2013-06-01
name2 2013-06-01
```

second.sql file has

```
name  date
name3 2013-06-01
name4 2013-06-01
```

i would have to append them in a single table .

Final table

```
name  date
name1 2013-06-01
name2 2013-06-01
name3 2013-06-01
name4 2013-06-01
```

> dump restore does truncate load

, i would like to append data at each sql restore command .

Comment: The .sql file is a script, you can edit it an remove part where it creates/drops the table.

Comment: Thanks a ton, This did the trick , i would like to write a script that removes creates/Drop from the .sql file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The .sql file is a script, you can edit it, and remove the part where it creates/drops the table.

If you're using `mysqldump`, you can add the `--skip-add-drop-table` and `--no-create-info` options so the drop/create table instructions won't be there in the first place

You can find more info on the [`mysqldump` documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump --skip-add-drop-table --no-create-info -u pentah_user -p test outtestactivity > outtestactivity1.sql`