# How I can import multiple sql file that has same schema into one database?

Tags: mysql

have multiple sql file that has same schema and I want to import it into one database without overwriting the data after the first import.

For Example: www.sql vvv.sql xxx.sql zzz.sql yyy.sql

First thing I do is import this www.sql and then when I import vvv.sql it's overwrite the database and only data of vvv.sql is in there

What is the best to do to put all the data of this (www.sql vvv.sql xxx.sql zzz.sql yyy.sql) into one database without overwriting the current data in the database ?

Comment: This question might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397661/append-mysql-dump-to-a-table

Comment: *when I import vvv.sql it's overwrite the database* This means that 2nd dump contains the commands which overwrites existing data (for example, this may be DROP/CREATE tables commands). You must cut these commands off. But this does not prevent the data interference. The most useful option seems to be importing all dumps to different temporary databases then collect them into working database saving the references integrity with additional queries.

Comment: how i can collect them and put the data to working database @Akina?

Comment: It is impossible to give a concrete answer to an abstract question.